# is there a way to change the sliding duration for carousel in bootsrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i was wondering if it was possible to change the duration of sliding in the carousel
i'm talking about this
[the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqqOv.gif)

the time when there's carousel-item-next

```
enter c.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
transition-property: opacity;
transition-duration: .5s;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .carousel-item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

i'm using this css for the fade animation but when you press you can actually see that it takes a second to start because of the sliding duration

I'm leaving a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w3o1y90p/6/

it's not properly formatted but it gives the idea

Comment: Can you provide a [codeply](https://codeply.com)?

Comment: i haven't found nothing around i only found this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#change-transition-duration but i have a hard time understand what i need to do ,probabilly because i have never used sass or sccs,

Answer (score 0):

Use inline CSS in HTML tag like:

```
<div class="slider" style="transition-duration: 5s;"></div>
```

//Adding **inline-style** overrides bootstrap CDN and transition duration is manually set.